# State not updating in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, weather-api

After I fetched data from an api I am trying to update a state, but it is not updating.
I am also getting the response successfully.
I have also added the calling function.
Here is the function and state :

```
const getWeather = async (lat, lon) => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${apiKey.apiKey}`;
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const response = await data.json();
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.main.temp);
    setWeather({
      lat: lat,
      lon: lon,
      temperature: Math.round(response.main.temp),
      feelstemp: Math.round(response.main.feels_like),
      desc: response.weather.description,
      humidity: response.main.humidity,
      pressure: response.main.pressure,
      visibility: response.visibilty,
      windspeed: response.wind.speed,
      sunrise: response.sys.sunrise,
      sunset: response.sys.sunset,
      city: response.city,
      country: response.sys.country,
      main: response.weather[0].main,
    });
    console.log(weather);
  };
//Calling function in another file.
useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      getLocation()
        //If user allow location service then will fetch data & send it to get-weather function.
        .then((position) => {
          getWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          //If user denied location service then standard location weather will le shown on basis of latitude & latitude.
          getWeather(28.67, 77.22);
          alert(
            "You have disabled location service. Allow 'This APP' to access your location. Your current location will be used for calculating Real time weather."
          );
        });
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation not available");
    }
  }, []);
```

Plese help me updating the state.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is successfully received through API means the code is working. But since in your code `setWeather` is a [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function, it is not called synchronously in the component and the log is not updating correctly. To log the output, you need to use a `useEffect` hook like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(weather);
}, [weather]);
```

This hook will detect the change in `setWeather` function whenever the `weather` state gets updated and trigger the log.

To learn more about `useEffect` hook, see official documentation here: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect

**Update: I just noticed there is a spelling error of the value `visibility` in your response.data JSON object. I recommend you should double-check the API reference to make sure it is correct.**

Comment: I am calling the function in different file using useeffect & I have also corrected the spelling mistake but it is still not updating

Comment: @AyushBansal Did you check whether the useEffect hook in the other file you mentioned is getting triggered and settting setWeather function? Kindly add a log inside useEffect hook to check it. I suspect that is the issue.

Comment: Can you check if the calling function is correct or not.

Comment: But I think the calling function is working because I am getting the response in console

Answer (score 0):

You still need to execute your function, you only defined the function `getWeather` but you still need to call it. You can not just go ahead and call `getWeather` later on in the code because of possible rerenders it will get fetched every time. You need to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for this.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  }, []);
```

But because you're using `getWeather` in the `useEffect` you need to add it to the dependency array:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  }, [getWeather]);
```

But because `getWeather` is not a callback function you need to wrap `getWeather` with `useCallback`

```js
const getWeather = useCallback(async (lat, lon) => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${apiKey.apiKey}`;
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const response = await data.json();
    setWeather({
      lat: lat,
      lon: lon,
      temperature: Math.round(response.main.temp),
      feelstemp: Math.round(response.main.feels_like),
      desc: response.weather.description,
      humidity: response.main.humidity,
      pressure: response.main.pressure,
      visibility: response.visibilty,
      windspeed: response.wind.speed,
      sunrise: response.sys.sunrise,
      sunset: response.sys.sunset,
      city: response.city,
      country: response.sys.country,
      main: response.weather[0].main,
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: i am calling the fumction using useeffect . and using callback function is also not working